# Postfix doesn't start on reboot

Tags: postfix, centos7, systemctl

I'm on CentOS 7 and as far as I understand, all that is needed for Postfix to start on reboot is to run
`systemctl enable postfix.service`

However, that doesn't work for me. After a reboot, `systemctl status postfix` produces the following:

`postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service; enabled)
Active: inactive (dead)`

There are no errors recorded in the error log and Postfix starts and works just fine when I do it manually.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: output from `cat /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/postfix.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Postfix Mail Transport Agent
After=syslog.target network.target
Conflicts=sendmail.service exim.service

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/spool/postfix/pid/master.pid
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/network
ExecStartPre=-/usr/libexec/postfix/aliasesdb
ExecStartPre=-/usr/libexec/postfix/chroot-update
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/postfix start
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/postfix reload
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/postfix stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Please post the result of `find /etc/systemd/system -name \*postfix\*`

Comment: The output is `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/postfix.service`

Comment: Seems ok. Nothing in mail.log or messages?  Is SELinux enabled? Try remove symlink `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/postfix.service` and enabled again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Federico, thank you very much for your help. I checked /var/log/messages and saw that on manual start, first sendmail is shut down and then postfix is started. I figured there might be some kind of sendmail/postfix conflict on restart so I did `yum remove sendmail` and it's all good now!